# After answer; question were marked as duplicate but doesn't solve the original question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

After answering this question, [Remove an element from the forced width that the parent container is applying to the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364213/remove-an-element-from-the-forced-width-that-the-parent-container-is-applying-to), it later became marked as a duplicate.

As some requirements were different, I added those to the "duplicate answer" and found it doesn't solve the original question.

I did vote for a reopen and as well flagged it, with a message how they do not match as the specifications are different, still no response on that though.

Should I also edit the original question adding a link to the "duplicate-target" with a description telling why they aren't duplicates?

Is there any other way, and should I try, to reach out to the user(s) marked it duplicate? I mean, they would see what I mean in an instant and likely be able to address it with less effort than anybody else.

**Edit**

Another way could of course be that I delete my answer at the original post and add it to the "duplicate", as an answer for those with that specific requirement ?

**Edit2**

But then again, as the accepted answer in the "duplicate-target" doesn't solve the original question, can/should they still be duplicates, where an accepted answer is valid for the "duplicate-target" and a non accepted answer is valid for the original question?

Comment: Are those *additional requirements* incidental to the question, or at its core? Is the existing answer are good and comprehensive answer, or is that the cause of its downfall?

Comment: When the "duplicate-target"'s answer is used to solve the original question, it fails, but the explanation is not wrong, but you need to know and understand how to use that answer and alter it to work for your specifics. The requirements is well explained in the original question so I believe it should have its own answer.

Comment: You aren't expected to copy-and-paste solutions from SO, but get the knowledge you miss. And the way you explain it, it's just that the solution has to be adjusted to fit.

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree completely, for people who has basic knowledge, to adjust a sample to their own needs is a better learning practice than copy-pasting, ... but for a newbie of the technology in question, to get an answer which does not solve their issue, I do believe an exact code snippet actually will help them better to learn from, as they see how their issue were solved with that particular code ... and in this case, the question/answer is quite easy to understand if one have some knowledge, but without, not so easy, and therefore I think the original question serves a purpose.

Comment: Then it seems that you think the OP would be better served on a tutoring site instead of SO...

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, I'm just taught, when someone ask for help and I feel they have less knowledge than I, to lower myself when answer/helping ... but of course, as "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. ", your are right, I should expect users here capable of make use of a less "copy-and-paste"-able answer.